# Change imageButton resource in dynamic listview

Tags: android, android-listview, getview

I have this piece of code:

```
 public void ON_function(View view) {
    int position = lv.getPositionForView(view);
    String pozycja = Integer.toString(position);
    String tile_content = listaurzadzen.get(position).toString().replace("{urzadzenie=", "\0").replace("}", "\0");
    String[] IP_substring = tile_content.split("\r\n");
    SendMessage(IP_substring[1].trim(), "switchon");
    //ImageButton bulb = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    //bulb.setImageResource(R.drawable.bulb_on);
}


public void OFF_function(View view) {
    int position = lv.getPositionForView(view);
    String pozycja = Integer.toString(position);
    String tile_content = listaurzadzen.get(position).toString().replace("{urzadzenie=", "\0").replace("}", "\0");
    String[] IP_substring = tile_content.split("\r\n");
    SendMessage(IP_substring[1].trim(), "switchoff");
    //ImageButton bulb = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    //bulb.setImageResource(R.drawable.bulb_off);
}
```

Two simple functions which are called from dynamically created listview rows, each sends a message or whatever.

My problem is, if I can get the position using (view) to get the string of specific row, why can't I use it to change the image button resource of this specific row? Do I really have to create all these `getView` methods to make it happen? If so how do I do it with a simple adapter. I have been looking for a solution for a long time.

Comment: Can you do ImageButton bulb = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton); ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you do

```
ImageButton bulb = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
bulb.setImageResource(R.drawable.bulb_off);
```